# Make CloudWatch Event pass an integer timestamp instead of string of UTC time

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-step-functions, aws-batch

I'm invoking a scheduled Step Function with a CloudWatch event. The input of the first batch job in the step function state machine is like the following:

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "sdjlafgdf05-7c32-435hf-aa3b5a8sfade815",
  "detail-type": "Scheduled Event",
  "source": "aws.events",
  "account": "xxxxxxxx",
  "time": "2022-01-14T19:46:49Z",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "resources": [
    "arn:aws:events:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:rule/adfnwelkqnlngqrej-SAFFJKHF734"
  ],
  "detail": {}
}
```

I want the `"time"` field can give me the integer. Specifically, instead of `"2022-01-14T19:46:49Z"`, I want `"1642189609"` (epoch in seconds), so I don't need to parse it in my batch job code. I'm using CDK to build the infrastructure. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment this is not possible directly with native Step Functions ["Intrinsic Functions"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html). So you have two options:

- Do it via a lambda as explained in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71064408/3460414)
- Pass it first to EventBridge and then create a rule for EventBridge to foward it to CloudWatch