# How to get epoch time in AWS Step Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, aws-step-functions

We can refer to the current time in AWS Step functions using "$$.State.EnteredTime", But that gives the ISO format. Is there a way to get the Epoch seconds/milliseconds? I want to add the TTL value in the DynamoDB based on that.

Is this possible? Or do I have to invoke a Lambda function only for the timestamp?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This requires a [Lambda Invoke Task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-lambda.html). A small set of value transformations (e.g. string interpolation, JSON parsing) are natively handled by [Intrinsic Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html).  Most value transforms, however, including date manipulation, require an external task resource like Lambda.

```json
"EpochExecutionTimeLambda": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "ResultPath": "$.epoch",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:...",
  "Parameters": {
    "dateTime.$": "$$.State.EnteredTime"
  }
```

The lambda handler is of course trivial:

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => new Date(event.dateTime).valueOf()
```

Answer (score 0):

As an additional tip, it's worth checking if services you are already using in your stepfunction may do this.

For example, if you're making a call to RDS in your stepfunction get the timestamp from there.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), ...restOfQuery
```

Either add the TTL you want directly (e.g. 1 month)

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP()+2592000, ...restOfQuery
```

or use intrinsic functions (also converting back to string for dynamo step)

```
States.JsonToString(States.MathAdd($.rds.unixTimestamp, 2592000))
```